# JQuery 1.7.1 .css('td',...) Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded

Tags: jquery, stack-overflow

I have a very large table on my page (821 x 205), and I have been using JQuery recently for applying CSS.  When I do this:

```
$('#main_table,th').css({
    'border':'solid 1px',
    'border-collapse': 'collapse'
});
```

There is no error, but when I add a td to the JQuery code, like this:

```
$('#main_table,th,td').css({
    'border':'solid 1px',
    'border-collapse': 'collapse'
});
```

I get the : `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Are there too many cells for jQuery?  Is there a better way to get all the borders that I want in the table?

Comment: It does sound more like a "number of elements" thing to me; naturally you should be using a style sheet instead of jQuery. JavaScript is just the wrong tool for this job altogether. But just out of curiousity, is the result the same if you fix the "border-collaps" typo? (should be "border-collapse")? Might be some sort of error buffer that's getting too full rather than a collection of nodes.

Comment: @GregPettit yes it still crashes with same error even after fixing the typo

Comment: Thanks for checking; I was simply curious. You've done the right thing switching to the CSS-based approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a better way to get all the borders that I want in the table?

Yes, put them in a style sheet!

```
#main_table, th, td {
    border: solid 1px,
    border-collapse: collapse
}
```

FWIW, if your intention is to *only* put this style on table cells that are included in `#main_table` then your selector is wrong, it should be:

```
#main_table th, #main_table td {
    ...
}
```

or even just

```
​#main_table tr > * {
    ...
}
```

​
As written, it'll apply it to *every* `<th>` and `<td>` regardless of which table they're in.